# Pretty text tables & trees

Tags: comments, ascii, command-line-interface

I'm wondering what SO uses (*if anything*) to create text-based tables and trees? I'm running Notepad++, however I'm thinking of making a change.

When I'm not whiteboarding, I'm in Notepad++, however it's a painstaking process creating both trees and tables. I've seen some quick scripts around for CLI driven processes, like file system output, but I'm looking for something that allows one to quickly create arbitrary tables and trees (*self contained GUI or file import perhaps*) and dump them to text. No plugins for Notepad++ in my searches.

I have various graphical modeling tools, however I prefer monospaced text (*I'm an ASCII art kid, not to mention for script docs inclusion*) so no sense in mentioning Visio (*blech*) or the plethora of others (*unless they happen to support this sort of functionality*)

```
+- Thank            +---------+----------------+
    |               | Any     | Suggestions    |
    +- You          +---------+----------------+
    |   |           | Are     | Certainly      |
    |   +- Very     +---------+----------------+
    |               | Welcome |                |
    +- Much         +---------+----------------+
```

Note: Running Win7x64 + Cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive about trees, but I have used the [perl Text::FormatTable](http://search.cpan.org/~trey/Text-FormatTable-1.03/lib/Text/FormatTable.pm) module before and have found it very very helpful in automatting output from scripts into tables.

For straight editing yourself, I'd recommend [org-mode](http://www.orgmode.org/) for emacs, which has a fantastic ascii table-editing mode.

Comment: **Thanks Wes Hardaker;** Good suggestions, I've already created a rather simple script (PHP) that dumps 2 dimensional arrays to tex tables, in a manner similar to `Text::FormatTable`, but it's of little use, as I'm looking for something a bit more direct. I'll have a look at `org-mode`, however my hopes are a simple sort of GUI (add-node, add-row, etc.) that dumps to text. I might end up just quickly authoring one for Notepad++.

Comment: I actually used the above perl module to create a very simple 'csvtotab' script that I use regularily to convert csv to tables.  It's thus very easy to simply call it, pass in a list of comma separated items and have it spit out an ascii table.  These days though, if I need a table, I usually end up using org-mode.  It's much more powerful and the tables can even contain formulas that will update cells based on calculations.